# Start statement with infinitive

Tags: conditionals, infinitives

Is it possible to use infinitive and start statement with it to express conditional statement?

For example:
To go out with you today, I need to finish my job.

If it isn't correct way, could you suggest the best way to express such statements?

Comment: Yes, though the infinitival clause is not a conditional but a purpose adjunct. It gives the purpose of finishing your job. Note that we could add "in order", as in "In order to go out with you today ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with starting a sentence with an infinitive, and the sentence you quote is correct.

Comment: One wonders where these crazy prohibitions come from.

Comment: The sentence is perfectly fine—but I don't think I'd describe it as being *conditional* (in the question, not your answer), aside from in an indirectly implied (and subjectively interpreted) sense.